# Redirecting with .htaccess file in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currenty, I am using `.htaccess` file to redirect users to `404.php` page when they mis-spell the url.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /mywebsite/404.php
```

In my parent directory, there are some folders like **css**, **js** in which stylesheets and js files are kept. URL for these directories is like this:

```
localhost/mywebsite/css
localhost/mywebsite/js
```

By typing above urls, all the files are listed in the browser and can be opened by clicking on them.

Is there any way to add these urls in **.htaccess** file and redirect the user to home page (`localhost/mywebsite`) when they try to type above urls on the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options -Indexes add to .htaccess

Comment: I also have a folder say "ABC" which contains PHP files. Now if I type the url "localhost/mywebsite/ABC", all the PHP files are listed. So, as per you, there is no way to restrict the user to type above url?

Comment: Okay, it shows forbidden message to user. It is fine for me. But it would be great if I am able to redirect the user to home page instead of showing forbidden message.

Comment: Create /mywebsite/403.php add in 403.php `<?php header('Location: example.com/'); ?>`. Add in .htaccess  `ErrorDocument 403 /mywebsite/403.php`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want to disable indexing? Have a look at [how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing).

Comment: @ddtpoison777- Thanks for the link. It shows forbidden message to user. It is fine for me. But it would be great if I am able to redirect the user to home page instead of showing forbidden message

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170098/redirect-on-deny-htaccess.

PS: the .htaccess, its capabilities and how php works with it is very well documented. I suggest googling as well. :)